# Run an Ansible task only when the variable contains a specific string

Tags: linux, ansible, conditional-statements, ansible-2.x

I have multiple tasks depend from the value of variable1. I want to check if the value is in `{{ variable1 }}` but I get an error:

```yaml
- name: do something when the value in variable1
  command: <command>
  when: "'value' in {{ variable1 }}"
```

I'm using ansible 2.0.2

Comment: Answer below works for me (well, I use it in `assert: ... that: ...`. What error do you see?

Answer (score 116):

If `variable1` is a string, and you are searching for a substring in it, this should work:

```
when: '"value" in variable1'
```

if `variable1` is an array or dict instead, `in` will search for the *exact* string as one of its items.

Comment: this method works better, won't trigger warning as in `result|search`

Comment: This only works in later versions of Ansible, for alternatives for earlier versions see other answers.

Comment: I was using that with ansible 1.9, if iI remember correctly; if I had to write it today I wouldn't use that.

Answer (score 51):

None of the above answers worked for me in ansible 2.3.0.0, but the following does:

```
when: variable1 | search("value")
```

In ansible 2.9 this is deprecated in favor of using ~ concatenation for variable replacement:

```
when: "variable1.find('v=' ~ value) == -1"
```

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#other-operators

Other options:

```
when: "inventory_hostname in groups[sync_source]"
```

Comment: +1 I prefer this answer.  You can also add 'not' before 'variable1' if you want to check that variable1 does not contain 'value'.  when: not variable1 | search("value")

Comment: What if you want to negate / not this? Like if "value" is not in `variable1`?

Comment: @SimonWoodside https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32786122/ansible-condition-when-string-not-matching

Comment: says this method to be deprecated in 2.9. Instead of using `result|search` use `result is search`

Comment: But the fact is I find `result|search` works better even with warning. Lot of discussion on this: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/22397

Comment: Use `'"value" in variable1'` as suggested in another solution, won't trigger warning.

Comment: using variable1.find is atrocious and unreadable compared to variable1 | search("")

Comment: `'"value" in var'` doesnt work when your using a partial string, thats the only problem, and why `search` would be nice.

Answer (score 42):

From Ansible 2.5

```
when: variable1 is search("value")
```

For negative scenarios

```
when: not variable1 is search("value")
```

Comment: Great it works in ansible 2.9! If I need a condition that works only when the variable does not contain a specific string, what is the correct syntax? I was thinking to something like this: `when: variable1 is not search("value")` but is not working...

Comment: Hi, it is `when: not variable1 is search("value")`

Comment: @imjoseangel, Please add "not" case to the answer too...

Comment: Does search supports more than 1 sub-string check in a variable? i.e. `when: var is search("substring1|substring2")` to search either "substring1" or "substring2" in variable `var`? Or we have to add that separately using `and`. If I have a condition `when: var is search("substring1") or var is seach("substring2) and host is search("vm001")` then, how can I club the first 2 conditions (with `or`) i.e. it becomes condition 1 and condition 2. Thanks. Use '(' ')'?

Comment: @imjoseangel so figured out that, `search("...")` is cool enough to multi-search pattern like `grep "substring[12]"` can do. First I thought if it can do something like `egrep` can do i.e. `egrep "substring1|substring2|coolsubstr3"` but it didn't. Then idea came, what if it can do `search("substring[12]"` and that worked in my case in `when` condition.

Answer (score 18):

Some of the answers no longer work as explained.

Currently here is something that works for me in ansible 2.6.x

```
 when: register_var.stdout is search('some_string')
```

Answer (score 9):

In Ansible version 2.9.2:

If your variable variable1 is declared:

`when: "'value' in variable1"`

If you registered variable1 then:

`when: "'value' in variable1.stdout"`

Answer (score 9):

This works for me in Ansible 2.9:

```
variable1 = www.example.com. 
variable2 = www.example.org. 

when: ".com" in variable1
```

and for not:

```
when: not ".com" in variable2
```

Answer (score 8):

This example uses regex_search to perform a substring search.

```
- name: make conditional variable
  command: "file -s /dev/xvdf"
  register: fsm_out

- name: makefs
  command: touch "/tmp/condition_satisfied"
  when: fsm_out.stdout | regex_search(' data')
```

ansible version: 2.4.3.0

Answer (score 6):

use this

> when: "{{ 'value' in variable1}}"

instead of

> when: "'value' in {{variable1}}"

Also for string comparison you can use

> when: "{{ variable1 == 'value' }}"

Comment: when does not need curly braces: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#id2 (today, no idea about 2013)

Answer (score 0):

If one wants to club more than one similar looking sub-strings in just one search(),  then a user can also do something like:

`when: variable1 is search("value[12]")`

**which will be similar to**:

`when: variable1 is search("value1") or variable1 is search("value2")`

:)

Answer (score -2):

I used

```
failed_when: not(promtool_version.stdout.find('1.5.2') != -1)
```

means - failed only when the previously registered variable "promtool_version" doesn't contains string '1.5.2'.